# Creating a new object and keeping it in the array

Tags: ruby

I have a situation when I need to create an object and immediately save it into an array. I have a class `Book`, and in class `Library` I have an `array BOOKS[]`

For example, I create  `HarryPotter = Book.new("Harry Potter and F_stone", "‎JK Rowling")` and then it saves into array `BOOKS[]` by name of book ("Harry Potter and F_stone").

So, I need a method that can solve this problem.

Comment: I suggest you to learn some Ruby basics.

Comment: I just started to learn Ruby and got the first homework on Ruby.But faced with such a problem here (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
class Book
  @@books = Array.new

  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
    @@books << self # Add the instance object into a static variable
  end

  def self.books
    puts @@books
  end
end
```

Use a static variable `@@books`.

```
(main) > load './books.rb'
=> true
(main) > foo = Book.new("Foo")
=> #<Book:0x00000105583120 @title="Foo">
(main) > bar = Book.new("Bar")
=> #<Book:0x00000106079f20 @title="Bar">
(main) > Book.books
#<Book:0x00000105583120>
#<Book:0x00000106079f20>
```